# why the program could not calculate BMI?

Tags: gcc, clang, bmi

```py
height=float(input('please enter your height in meters:')) 
weight=float(input('please enter your weight in kilograms:'))
BMI=weight/(height**2)
print('your BMI:')
```

I tried to calculate BMI using weight and height but after running the program BMI was not        calculated and returned to the first line.

Answer (score 0):

I think the BMI is calculated correctly, you just forgot to print the actual value (the result of your calculation). Try it like this:

```py
print('your BMI:', BMI)
```